# Package "dcurves" in R enables DCA curve drawing of COX models in a variety of situations

Tags: r

I would like to use the 'dcurves' package to draw the DCA curves of the Nomogram, T stage, and N stage models. Is the following code correct?

Thanks a lot

#Using dcurves package plot Nomogram/T stage/N stage DCA

```
library(dcurves)

Nomogram <- coxph(Surv(Survivalmonths,status)~Age_group+Histologic+T+N+Surgery+Radiation,data=data.train)
T_stage <- coxph(Surv(Survivalmonths,status)~T,data=data.train)
N_stage <- coxph(Surv(Survivalmonths,status)~N,data=data.train)

tbl_regression(Nomogram, exponentiate = TRUE)

data.train_updated1 <- broom::augment( Nomogram, newdata = data.train %>% mutate(Survivalmonths = 36), type.predict = "expected" ) %>% mutate( Nomogram = 1 - exp(-.fitted) ) 
data.train_updated2 <- broom::augment( T_stage, newdata = data.train %>% mutate(Survivalmonths = 36), type.predict = "expected" ) %>% mutate( T_stage = 1 - exp(-.fitted) ) 
data.train_updated3 <- broom::augment( N_stage, newdata = data.train %>% mutate(Survivalmonths = 36), type.predict = "expected" ) %>% mutate( N_stage = 1 - exp(-.fitted) ) 

df <- merge(x=data.train_updated1,y=data.train_updated2,by=".rownames", all.x = TRUE)
df <- merge(x=df,y=data.train_updated3,by=".rownames", all.x = TRUE)

dca(Surv(Survivalmonths,status) ~ Nomogram+T_stage+N_stage, 
    data = df,
    time = 36,
    thresholds = 1:100 / 100) %>%
  plot(smooth = TRUE)
```

Comment: I _think_ you have the correct formula. But to be certain, I would follow the formulas found in this decision curve analysis tutorial https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/dca-tutorial/dca-tutorial-r.html#DCA_for_Survival_Outcomes

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, Professor Daniel.  I will study hard above link.